# Mixing liquids when applying a voltage

Tags: electromagnetism, experimental-physics, physical-chemistry

I'm thinking in the following experiment:

**A)** Two (non mixable (like water and oil)) liquids are going to lie in a container, in the extremes of the container there are two electrodes, those electrodes will have a potential difference $\Phi$. Just as the figure $1.a)$.

I'm looking for  some interesting liquids that mix, change of color when a voltage difference is present.

[image]

**B)** The next one is really similar, now there are some solid particle present, analogously I look for a mixture that has different properties when a voltage difference is present.

I'm a physics student that want to study different properties of mixtures when applying different voltage differences, and maybe study the diffusion of the solid particles when they mix, if the diffusion coefficient is grater, etc.

Any help with the liquids that has this property is really  appreciated.

Cross posted [Chemistry.stackexchange](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/19456/mixing-liquids-when-applying-a-voltage)